# If he owns a Cadillac, I own an invisibility cloak

Tags: conditional-constructions, sarcasm

Does B's reply sound natural in the following dialogue? Here, he is obviously denying he has an invisibility cloak to show he doesn't believe John has a Cadillac. **Are there any constraints on this pattern?** Some people say I should begin the main clause with "I am . . . " with this pattern to indicate absurdity. Is that necessary?

> A: Did you know John owns a Cadillac?

> B: If he owns a Cadillac, I own an invisibility cloak.

I am wondering whether there is a punchiness requirement on the main clause of this pattern.

Compare the following sentences:

> 1. If that's Princess Anne, then I'm able to fly from Zurich to San Francisco in just under two hours and wenty minutes.

> 2. If that’s Princess Anne, I’m a Dutchman.

> 3. If John owns a Cadillac, I own an invisibility cloak.

Comment: Please stop asking questions about whether something sounds natural. It boils down to editing.

Comment: Don't you see "Are there any constraints on this pattern"?

Comment: Your inability to answer the question does not mean it is an inappropriate one.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that anyone would use such a cumbersome comparison as your sentence 1.

Comment: How do you feel about sentence 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern is

**if** `something possible, but not believed by the speaker`, **then** `something ridiculous, impossible, or obviously untrue`

Examples:

If he has a university degree, (then) I'm a Dutchman (said by somebody not Dutch)

If that's a good paint job, (then) I'm a monkey's uncle.

If he owns a Cadillac, my name is Jesus J. Jones. (said by someone whose name is not that).

There is a similar pattern, where we wish to assert that something is, or will be found to be, true:

`Statement believed to be true` **or** `something ridiculous, impossible, or obviously untrue`

The main clause can be one also commonly used to indicate disbelief. Examples:

(I see a man in the distance) - that's John Smith, or I'm a Dutchman!

They'll be divorced in a year, or my name's not Michael Harvey.

Comment: I'm wondering whether the main clause can use expressions other the ones you listed.

Comment: Some people say I should begin the main clause with "I am . . . " with this pattern to indicate absurdity.

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: All of your examples begin with "I am . . . " But I have also seen "If grannie is here, she is invisible."

Comment: And I'm interested in how you perceive "If John owns a Cadillac, I own an invisibility cloak."

Comment: Ah, I see. No, 'I am' is not essential. You could put something pithy, scurrilous or ridiculous as a main clause, e.g. If John owns a Cadillac, my name is Frank Fuck.

Comment: If Joe Smith was a navy officer, Donald Trump has the Fields Medal.

Comment: I would not take "If grannie is here, she is invisible" as an example of the pattern; it's simply saying “I cannot see her”.  The pattern implies “Without specific evidence on the claim, I have other reasons to believe it is unlikely.”